# sed command to swap words not working

Tags: sed

I'm trying to swap words in each line using sed like so:

```
sed 's/\([^ ]*\), \([^ ]*\)/\2, \1/' sed.txt
```

And this is sed.txt:

```
FIRST LAST
FIRST LAST
FIRST LAST
FIRST LAST
```

But it's not working and I'm not sure why, my desired outcome is:

```
LAST FIRST
LAST FIRST
LAST FIRST
LAST FIRST
```

I know the example is insignificant but I'd like to understand sed more because I've only been using it for swapping words in their current position without changing positions.

Comment: With GNU sed: `sed -E 's/(.*) (.*)/\2 \1/' file`

Comment: For the given sample, you can also use `awk '{print $2, $1}'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed 's/\([^ ]*\), \([^ ]*\)/\2, \1/' sed.txt
```

The problem is first comma because in source text you do not have it. Change it:

```
sed 's/\([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\)/\2, \1/' sed.txt
```

and will work

Comment: Haha derp, thank you!

Comment: Also beware that `*` matches 0-or-more. You may want to replace it with `\{1,\}` for 1-or-more. Would make a difference if there were lines starting with space characters.

Comment: Note that your expression still _inserts_ a comma at the end of the first field.

Comment: @Kusalananda, true. I just try to do minimal edit of OP expression.